# How to stop listening for snapshot updates in cloud firestore in Vuejs?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, chat

I'm using firestore in a messaging app I wrote with Vuejs.

**The scenario is as follows:** Active conversations are listed on the left side of the screen, clicking on it connects to the relevant collection and messages are listed on the right. So far everything is great.

**Problem:** When I click on each chat on the left, it connects to the corresponding collection. If more than one connection is made, the problem arises. While messaging with person A and receive a message from person B, the data in my right message box will change to B (Because I just clicked on that chat and subscribed to the collection).

Here is the function I run to list chats on page load:

```
mounted() {
        const me = this.getRandomNumber()

        firestore.collection('chat-groups').doc('messages').collection(`${me}`).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            this.chatGroups = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            }))
        })
    },
```

Here is the function I run to list messages when I click on chat:

```
async getChatDetails(e) {
            const me = this.getRandomNumber()
            const pairId = e.id
            this.activeChat.id = pairId
            this.activeChat.userName = e.name
            this.activeChat.profilePhoto = e.photo

            firestore.collection('chat-groups').doc('messages').collection(`${me}`).doc(`${pairId}`).collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(250).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                this.messages = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                })).reverse()
            })

            this.chatIsSelected = true
        }
```

This is how I printed the messages stored in the this.messages variable to the page:

```
<ChatArea :messages="messages" />
```

I tried the following to close the connection but no results

```
firestore.collection('chat-groups').doc('messages').collection(`${me}`).onSnapshot()
```

```
firestore.collection().onSnapshot()
```

The solution I could think of was to unsubscribe from the previous subscription and start a new one when I clicked on a chat, but I was unable to do so.

As a result I want to be able to close the previous link both when I leave the page (beforeDestroy) and when I click on the other chat.

Answer (score 0):

as you know that previous listener is not detached after you leave the previous chat and create a new listener for a new collection. so it still listening, i assume that you using options api, you can create a data "id" that will used for getting collection of message from props, and "listener" data for listening variable

attach listener data to snapshot in mounted function, after that create a watcher that watching data id changed or not, if changed, detach the listener variable and attach new listener with new id from props in watcher